# Как настроить ElasticSearch, чтобы он искал сначала по более длинному токену/терму?

Tags: elasticsearch

По фразе **экспедиц** ES находит сначала **экс**курсии, потом ме**диц**ина и только потом **экспедиц**ии.

Насколько я понимаю, запрос разбивается на: **экс эксп экспе** и так далее. А затем осуществляется поиск сначала по **экс**, потом по **эксп** и по всем токенам. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как заставить искать в обратном порядке (сначала по токенам с большим количеством символов) или как изменить развернуть список токенов, чтобы выглядело так **экспе эксп экс**?

Или как настроить релевантность, чтобы по запросу **экспедиц** в результатах сначала отображались экспедиции, а потом уже сопутствующие результаты?

**Индекс** (пробовал убирать/добавлять список стоп-слов)

```
$settings = [
        'settings' => [
            'number_of_shards' => 1,
            'number_of_replicas' => 1,
            "analysis" => [
                'analyzer' => [
                    'ru_analyzer' => [
                        'type' => 'custom',
                        "tokenizer" => 'nGram',
                        "filter" => [
                            "lowercase",
                            'ru_stopwords',
                            'kstem',
                            'snowball',
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
                'tokenizer' => [
                    'nGram' => [
                        'type' => 'nGram',
                        'min_gram' => 3,
                        'max_gram' => 5,
                    ],
                ],
                'filter' => [
                    'ru_stopwords' => [
                        'type' => 'stop',
                        'stopwords' => 'а,без,более,бы,был,была,были,было,быть,в,вам,вас,весь,во,вот,все,всего,всех,вы,где,да,даже,для,до,его,ее,если,есть,еще,же,за,здесь,и,из,или,им,их,к,как,ко,когда,кто,ли,либо,мне,может,мы,на,надо,наш,не,него,нее,нет,ни,них,но,ну,о,об,однако,он,она,они,оно,от,очень,по,под,при,с,со,так,также,такой,там,те,тем,то,того,тоже,той,только,том,ты,у,уже,хотя,чего,чей,чем,что,чтобы,чье,чья,эта,эти,это,я,a,an,and,are,as,at,be,but,by,for,if,in,into,is,it,no,not,of,on,or,such,that,the,their,then,there,these,they,this,to,was,will,with',
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'mappings' => $this->_mapping ?? $this->createMap(),
    ];
```

**Маппинг**

```
$default = [
"properties" => [
    "uid_content" => ["type" => "text"],
    "body" => [
        "type" => "text",
        "analyzer" => "ru_analyzer",
        "term_vector" => "with_positions_offsets"
    ],
    "title" => [
        "type" => "text",
        "analyzer" => "ru_analyzer",
        "term_vector" => "with_positions_offsets"
    ],
    "tags" => ["type" => "text", "fielddata" => true],
    "type_content" => ["type" => "text", "fielddata" => true],
    "author_name" => [
        "type" => "text",
        "analyzer" => "ru_analyzer",
        "term_vector" => "with_positions_offsets"
    ],
    "dt" => ["type" => "date", "format" => "yyyy-MM-dd"],
    "link" => ["type" => "text"],
]
];
```

Comment: `"sort": [
    {
      "_score": "desc"
    }
  ]` пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал и desc, и asc результат не изменяется.

Comment: Может у вас аналайзер настроен так, что слово просто сокращается и естественно он выдает другой результат? Вообще я пользуюсь плагином head, где можно наглядно увидеть что эластик ищет и проще составить запрос. Еще может быть дело в маппинге, с ним мб стоит поколдовать, раз он не находит то, что вам нужно.